# What does "*password------------" mean in a profile deadlock report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, deadlock, profiler

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I got several deadlock reports that have "*password------------" in the input buffer. It looks like an attack but in that case I don't know the reason or the kind of attack.

(the log was generated by an expert DBA how has lot of experience and told me that, not me)

Does anyone know what it is? Thanks!

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blocked-process>
  <process id="process879948" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057602473263104 (1d69201d0ba6)" waittime="5185" ownerId="88389135" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2012-09-25T18:11:02.507" XDES="0x1f7d2a590" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="4552" status="suspended" spid="86" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2012-09-25T18:11:02.507" lastbatchcompleted="2012-09-25T18:11:02.507" lastattention="2012-09-25T18:07:35.740" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="IP-xxxxxxxx" hostpid="4868" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="88389135" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
      <frame line="14" stmtstart="374" stmtend="764" sqlhandle="0x03000500dac2967f208e4000a19d00000000000000000000"/>
      <frame line="1" stmtstart="44" sqlhandle="0x02000000632f7e131f79ec7312284505961e537a61b81be7"/>
      <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"/>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>

*password---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   </inputbuf>
  </process>
</blocked-process>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It just means that the text of the statement contained the string "password" and SQL Server "helpfully" has masked it as a security feature to prevent you seeing some one else's password.

I was able to reproduce this as follows

```
CREATE TABLE T(X varchar(1000))
```

### Connection 1

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO T VALUES('password1') 

WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00'

SELECT * FROM T WHERE X = 'password2'

ROLLBACK
```

### Connection 2

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO T VALUES('password2') 

WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00'

SELECT * FROM T WHERE X = 'password1'

ROLLBACK
```

[Then retrieving the graph from the extended events trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/deadlock-error-isnt-returning-the-deadlock-sql/10646#10646)

Comment: @DiegoJancic - As for whether this is an attack or not it depends if you expect legitimate queries to contain this string or not. If you don't have any object names containing this string then maybe it could indicate a SQL injection attempt.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith, in my case it's not attack, I have a users table with a password field. Thanks again! =)

Comment: Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: @jlb - Not that I'm aware of. You could raise a request here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback and maybe you'll find out there is some way though.

Comment: @MartinSmith Have asked in the MSDN forums and all replies indicate that there's no way to disable this functionality.